# Is it possible to run multiple functions side by side in javascript even if they are not triggered at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

My script runs as follows:

```
//Gets triggered when a button is clicked
function button_1() {
    ...
    setTimeout(other_function(), 0);
    ...
}

//Checks if for hundreds of thumbnails a high-res version is available
function other_function() {
    ...
    $.ajax({
        url: url_to_highres_file,
        type: 'HEAD',
        cache: false,
        error: function() {
            $(#output).text('The file ' + filename_of_current_file + ' is not available!');
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

I understand that when the function "button_1" is triggered it executes code until the function "other_function" is triggered. From that point on both functions run pseudo simultaneously. The problem I have now is, that the function "other_function" runs for a long time. While that function is running and the user triggers another function e.g. "button_2", then javascript finishes the function "other_function" first before it starts executing code within the function "button_2".

Since the function "other_function" does not have that high of a priority to the user it is more important that the website responds to input rather than finishing the function "other_function" first.

Is there a way to still execute code blocks from the function "other_function" but also mix code blocks from the function "button_2" in between, so they run side by side and the user does not have to wait until the function "other_function" has finished?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I would suggest looking into webworkers for this as it would allow your other_function code to run in a separate process and this simultaneously. JS in a browser is single threaded. So although its event driven and not linear, it can still only execute one function at a time. Workers get around that by starting a new independent thread.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possible ways to approach it, depending on what you mean by "side by side". If you are talking about actually **simultaneously** executing code, it can **only** be achieved by multithreading, because you can imagine code like a literal thread going through the CPU, traditionally also described as a "tape" ( because that's what it used to be ).

The only way to process simultaneously is by using multiple threads, multiple CPU cores instead of one. This way even if one thread takes a long time ( it blocks ), other threads are still being processed. The other advantage is that two threads are actually getting processed twice as fast, because you are using double the processing power ( or more, depending on how many threads you can use ).

Javascript has no multithreading support as it's simple by design. If you are writing Javascript for the browser your only choice is using the [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) API, nodejs has a very similar [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) API in the standard library, as well a frameworks.

The second approach is called "subroutines", where rather than doing the entire expensive computation, you split it up into many small chunks and return control after every one of them, so other computations can be made ( for example handling of events ) between those chunks.

The third, the "asynchronous" approach is irrelevant for your problem. I'm just mentioning it because it's the best approach for many very similar looking problems. Instead of doing multiple computations side by side, people often just want functions to "wait for something". It's a completely different topic, but a very popular one to be confused about.

Comment: Thank you Winchestro! I will look into Web Workers.

Comment: @Flimzy thanks for taking the time reviewing this 1 year old answer, it could indeed use some improvement / clarification. I didn't say __any__ of the things your critisize it for, but that means my answer must be confusing. So I'm trying to make it less confusing.

Comment: It is much clearer now.  My apologies if I misunderstood, but thank you for improving the answer just the same.

Comment: I don't know how this works in javascript - that's why I came here ;) - but in other languages control can be returned inside of the function, freezing function, and jumping to another one. Well, at least that's how goroutines (or even single routine) work in golang. This way code can be run parallel on one thread. This could be pretty useful in javascript as long running function (e.g. infinite for loop in func) currently blocks browser, while with this approach it could keep that running but also allow to run other js events.